# CSS box shadow appears after delay when using animation on parent div

Tags: html, css, css-animations, box-shadow

so I have multiple div's and they appear using css animation, but when is box shadow used inside div's children it appears with delay. 
I add fiddle with exact example how it looks in my project.
Take attention at headers `box-shadow` when running code.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/a7Lu3nxx/

So I find out that, if I use `animation-fill-mode: forwards or both`, then box shadow is hidden behind the table, if I use `animation-fill-mode: backwards`, then box-shadow appears, but after delay.

My question is, how to load box shadow without that ugly delay and without using JS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are fading in both the `container` divs. Your box shadow is going to appear after the animation. If you want it to be shown straight away I would suggest you wrap the upper container and set the `box-shadow` to it like in the fiddle below.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/25jzuawc/1/

Based on your comment would you mind the box-shadow fading in? This will not have the ugly "all of a sudden" appearance of the box-shadow:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/25jzuawc/2/

Without the `first-child` you should use box-shadow inset:

Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/25jzuawc/3/

Comment: Hmm, I could do that, but reason why all my content is in separate containers, because I'm using ng-repeat method with AngularJs, so it's not very easy add wrapper around container which is made by repeater.

Comment: I updated my answer to maybe accommodate your request using repeat.

Comment: Thats very close, but another problem is, that my header element is not always first child.

Comment: I actually was about to edit my answer just as you commented. Realised that you would probably not have the container always as the first element. Sorry about that. But yeah, then you could use the inset box-shadow as in the third fiddle.

Comment: I used your 2nd advice. My element is not allways first child, but allways it is  2nd element from bottom, so I used `div:nth-last-child(2){
            box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
            z-index: 9;
            position: relative;
        }`

Comment: Ok, given that you know how your html is formed you will have to make the final decision but glad I could be helpful to you :)